# Streaming images to react page

Tags: reactjs, streaming, real-time

I need to find a solution to manage a flow of images that are created in real-time with the React framework.

Basically I have a back-end that continuously is creating and saving images into a folder. The front-end whenever a new image is created has to render it. I have already a system that manages asynchronously the event of a new image created, but I am not able to manage the real-time rendering of the images.

Anyone has an intuition about what is the proper technology/framework to handle this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Look into socket.io (websockets/classic polling)

Comment: you can use Socket.io. After you save the image in a filesystem or somewhere just emit the image url to the client/room, collect it and handle it.

Comment: But the problem here is not how to handle the push notification of a new image rendered, I'm already using Pusher for achieving that. The main problem is the rendering of the image: if I simply change the url of the image, given the high speed of the new images creation, the page is simply freezing and the image basically will never appear.